# Is there any easy way to get the data of a modal in Bootstrap 4

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I've been using [Vex-Modals](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vex-js/3.0.0/css/vex.min.css) so far but want to try bootstrap 4 now. 
I read the whole [Modal-Page of bootstrap.com](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/), but I didn't find a way as easy to get the form-data of a modal as in vex.

What I found out so far: This is possible:

```
$('#myModal').on('hide.bs.modal', function (e) {
  // ask value of $("#form-input1")
  // ask value of $("#form-input2")
  // ask value of $("#form-input3")
})
```

Vex works with a callback whose parameter `data` (an object) has all those values saved in it when I click `Ok` and the callback is called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest thing you can do, is to create the markup of the modal as a `<form>`. This will allow you to access both the `.modal()` and the `<form>` objects from the various event (e.g. `hidden.bs.modal`) handlers as `this`.

When you have access to the form itself, you could either use the [`.serializeArray()`](https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) method of jQuery or use the native [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects#Retrieving_a_FormData_object_from_an_HTML_form) class like in the example below.

```js
$('#modal-form').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (event) {
    // `this` is the modal window, which is also a `<form>` in our case

    // Option 1: using `.serializeArray()` of jQuery
    var fieldsAsArray = $(this).serializeArray();
    console.log('fieldsAsArray', fieldsAsArray);

    // Option 2: using native `FormData` object
    var fieldsAsFormData = new FormData(this);
    console.log('fieldsAsFormData', fieldsAsFormData);
});
```

```html
<!-- Note the `<form>` tag -->
<form class="modal fade" id="modal-form" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modal-dialogLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="modal-dialogLabel">Modal title</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

                <!-- actual form markup -->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="field1">Example label</label>
                    <input name="field1" type="text" class="form-control" id="field1" placeholder="Example input">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="field2">Another label</label>
                    <input name="field2" type="text" class="form-control" id="field2" placeholder="Another input">
                </div>
                <!-- /actual form markup -->

            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button id="save" data-dismiss="modal" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-form">
    Open modal form
</button>


<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Note: Even though the “Save changes” button is of type *submit*, the form won’t get submitted directly this way, since there is the `data-dismiss="modal"` attribute as well. That attribute captures the click event with an `event.preventDefault();` call. I believe this fits into your scenario as you want to work on the form data without first submitting it.

Answer (score 0):

To get all the form-data from that modal you can use [serialize](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) function. But if you want to construct js object from that set of form-data, there is another option. You can use [serializeArray](https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) function. Here is a stack-overflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184624/convert-form-data-to-javascript-object-with-jquery) where you can find how to convert a serialized array to js object. Hope this will solve your problem.